# How can I specify maximum size of a pdf/doc file in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

In my project, user can upload a pdf/doc/ppt file. I want to restrict uploading the file which is beyond 15MB. How can I achieve it in C#? Can I check in .cshtml(UI page) file? If yes, then please let me know how to do it in C# and Javascript/jQuery?